# Как подгрузить modelView из контроллера в modal dialog

Tags: java, ajax, spring, thymeleaf

Есть ссылка в навбаре при нажатии на которую открывается мод окно.Само окно написано в отдельной странице и подключается фрагментом в нужных местах.Так же есть контроллер который собирает простую modelView.

Вопрос:

Как из контроллера отправить modelView в это окно?

Юзаю спринг бут спринг дата займлиф

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" th:href="'#closeShiftModalId'">Закрытие смены</a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout">Выход</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Само модал окно

```
<div th:fragment="closeShift">
<div align="center" class="modal fade" th:id="'closeShiftModalId'">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Закрытие смены</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="/closeShift" method="POST" class="form-signin">
                        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Заполните Поля</h2>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"   placeholder="апро" required="" autofocus="" />
                        <br></br>

                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <th> Фамилия </th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tbody  th:each="allWorker : ${allWorker}">
                            <tr>
                                <td th:text="${allWorker.lastName}" ></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">!!!!!!!</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "спринг бут спринг дата займлиф" лол

Comment: Создай контроллер для страницы.